# How to make the button's left margin always equal the table left margin?

Tags: html, css

[image: What I want]

Hello everyone,

I'm using HTML/CSS and have this table centered on the page using the CSS class

```
.tablecenter    { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

I also have this button after the table:

```
<input type = "button" value = "Create Listening GIFT" style="???">
```

However, as you can see in the picture, the button is drawn straight on the left.

**What I want**: I want my button to be drawn from the position where the table's first column starts. Moreover, since when I change the browser page size the table's left margin also changes, I want the button 'to follow' the table and change its left margin respectively. In other words, no matter how I change the browser window size, I want my button to be exactly under the table.

How can I do that?

CODE:

```
<div>
        <table class = "tablecenter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="height:80px">
                        <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 1</span>
                    </th>
                    <th style="height:80px">
                        <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 2</span>
                    </th>
                    <th style="height:80px">
                        <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 3</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <!-- Listening - Part 1-->
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id = "col1">
                    <label> <span class = "spc7">Speaker A:</span>
                        <select name = "speakerA">
                            <option>Statement 1</option>
                            <option>Statement 2</option>
                            <option>Statement 3</option>
                            <option>Statement 4</option>
                            <option>Statement 5</option>
                            <option>Statement 6</option>
                            <option>Statement 7</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <p></p>

                    <label> <span class = "spc7">Speaker B:</span>
                        <select name = "speakerB">
                            <option>Statement 1</option>
                            <option>Statement 2</option>
                            <option>Statement 3</option>
                            <option>Statement 4</option>
                            <option>Statement 5</option>
                            <option>Statement 6</option>
                            <option>Statement 7</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <label> <span class = "spc7">Speaker C:</span>
                        <select name = "speakerC">
                            <option>Statement 1</option>
                            <option>Statement 2</option>
                            <option>Statement 3</option>
                            <option>Statement 4</option>
                            <option>Statement 5</option>
                            <option>Statement 6</option>
                            <option>Statement 7</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <label> <span class = "spc7">Speaker D:</span>
                        <select name = "speakerD">
                            <option>Statement 1</option>
                            <option>Statement 2</option>
                            <option>Statement 3</option>
                            <option>Statement 4</option>
                            <option>Statement 5</option>
                            <option>Statement 6</option>
                            <option>Statement 7</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <p></p>

                    <label> <span class = "spc7">Speaker E:</span>
                        <select name = "speakerE">
                            <option>Statement 1</option>
                            <option>Statement 2</option>
                            <option>Statement 3</option>
                            <option>Statement 4</option>
                            <option>Statement 5</option>
                            <option>Statement 6</option>
                            <option>Statement 7</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <label> <span class = "spc7">Speaker F:</span>
                        <select name = "speakerF">
                            <option>Statement 1</option>
                            <option>Statement 2</option>
                            <option>Statement 3</option>
                            <option>Statement 4</option>
                            <option>Statement 5</option>
                            <option>Statement 6</option>
                            <option>Statement 7</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </td>

                <!-- Listening - Part 2-->
                <td id = "col2">
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Statement A</u>:</span>
                    <label>1) - True:
                        <input name = "statementA" type = "radio"
                               value = "1) - True" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2) - False:
                        <input name = "statementA" type = "radio"
                               value = "2) - False">
                    </label>
                    <label>3) - Not Stated:
                        <input name = "statementA" type = "radio"
                               value = "3) - Not Stated">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Statement B</u>:</span>
                    <label>1) - True:
                        <input name = "statementB" type = "radio"
                               value = "1) - True" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2) - False:
                        <input name = "statementB" type = "radio"
                               value = "2) - False">
                    </label>
                    <label>3) - Not Stated:
                        <input name = "statementB" type = "radio"
                               value = "3) - Not Stated">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Statement C</u>:</span>
                    <label>1) - True:
                        <input name = "statementC" type = "radio"
                               value = "1) - True" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2) - False:
                        <input name = "statementC" type = "radio"
                               value = "2) - False">
                    </label>
                    <label>3) - Not Stated:
                        <input name = "statementC" type = "radio"
                               value = "3) - Not Stated">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Statement D</u>:</span>
                    <label>1) - True:
                        <input name = "statementD" type = "radio"
                               value = "1) - True" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2) - False:
                        <input name = "statementD" type = "radio"
                               value = "2) - False">
                    </label>
                    <label>3) - Not Stated:
                        <input name = "statementD" type = "radio"
                               value = "3) - Not Stated">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Statement E</u>:</span>
                    <label>1) - True:
                        <input name = "statementE" type = "radio"
                               value = "1) - True" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2) - False:
                        <input name = "statementE" type = "radio"
                               value = "2) - False">
                    </label>
                    <label>3) - Not Stated:
                        <input name = "statementE" type = "radio"
                               value = "3) - Not Stated">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Statement F</u>:</span>
                    <label>1) - True:
                        <input name = "statementF" type = "radio"
                               value = "1) - True" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2) - False:
                        <input name = "statementF" type = "radio"
                               value = "2) - False">
                    </label>
                    <label>3) - Not Stated:
                        <input name = "statementF" type = "radio"
                               value = "3) - Not Stated">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Statement G</u>:</span>
                    <label>1) - True:
                        <input name = "statementG" type = "radio"
                               value = "1) - True" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2) - False:
                        <input name = "statementG" type = "radio"
                               value = "2) - False">
                    </label>
                    <label>3) - Not Stated:
                        <input name = "statementG" type = "radio"
                               value = "3) - Not Stated">
                    </label>
                </td>

                <!-- Listening - Part 3-->
                <td id = "col3">
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Question 3</u>:</span>
                    <label>1)
                        <input name = "question 3" type = "radio"
                               value = "1" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2)
                        <input name = "question 3" type = "radio"
                               value = "2">
                    </label>
                    <label>3)
                        <input name = "question 3" type = "radio"
                               value = "3">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Question 4</u>:</span>
                    <label>1)
                        <input name = "question 4" type = "radio"
                               value = "1" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2)
                        <input name = "question 4" type = "radio"
                               value = "2">
                    </label>
                    <label>3)
                        <input name = "question 4" type = "radio"
                               value = "3">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Question 5</u>:</span>
                    <label>1)
                        <input name = "question 5" type = "radio"
                               value = "1" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2)
                        <input name = "question 5" type = "radio"
                               value = "2">
                    </label>
                    <label>3)
                        <input name = "question 5" type = "radio"
                               value = "3">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Question 6</u>:</span>
                    <label>1)
                        <input name = "question 6" type = "radio"
                               value = "1" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2)
                        <input name = "question 6" type = "radio"
                               value = "2">
                    </label>
                    <label>3)
                        <input name = "question 6" type = "radio"
                               value = "3">
                    </label>


                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Question 7</u>:</span>
                    <label>1)
                        <input name = "question 7" type = "radio"
                               value = "1" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2)
                        <input name = "question 7" type = "radio"
                               value = "2">
                    </label>
                    <label>3)
                        <input name = "question 7" type = "radio"
                               value = "3">
                    </label>


                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Question 8</u>:</span>
                    <label>1)
                        <input name = "question 8" type = "radio"
                               value = "1" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2)
                        <input name = "question 8" type = "radio"
                               value = "2">
                    </label>
                    <label>3)
                        <input name = "question 8" type = "radio"
                               value = "3">
                    </label>

                    <p></p>
                    <span class = "spc7"><u>Question 9</u>:</span>
                    <label>1)
                        <input name = "question 9" type = "radio"
                               value = "1" checked>
                    </label>
                    <label>2)
                        <input name = "question 9" type = "radio"
                               value = "2">
                    </label>
                    <label>3)
                        <input name = "question 9" type = "radio"
                               value = "3">
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
            <input type = "button" value = "Create Listening GIFT">
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a working code?

Comment: Try wrapping your table and button with a div and set the div's style as display:flex and justify-content:center

Comment: Working code of what? The whole code is around 370 lines and I can't paste it here. It's pure HTML/CSS, no JS or anything else (I started a couple of days ago). Most of the code is listing the options for various input tools (radiobuttons, text fields, etc).

Comment: Add a code of your table and button

Comment: Added the code.

@ Geeky
It didn't work, it drew the button as the 4th column of the table.

Comment: just to be clear you want the button in the center of the table? yes or no

Comment: No. On the left, so it could be right where the right vertical line in my picture is.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; rule from the table.
Apply these css styles on the parent div along with display:table.

```
div {
      margin: auto;
      display: table;
    }
```

This will make sure button always stays on the starting of the first column of the

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your code with div and set it some width as 880px as we already know the width of table and set is margin-left and right as auto

```css
div{
    margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:900px;
}
table{
  
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <table class="tablecenter">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="height:80px">
              <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 1</span>
            </th>
            <th style="height:80px">
              <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 2</span>
            </th>
            <th style="height:80px">
              <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 3</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <!-- Listening - Part 1-->
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td id="col1">
              <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker A:</span>
                <select name="speakerA">
                  <option>Statement 1</option>
                  <option>Statement 2</option>
                  <option>Statement 3</option>
                  <option>Statement 4</option>
                  <option>Statement 5</option>
                  <option>Statement 6</option>
                  <option>Statement 7</option>
                </select>
              </label>
              <p></p>

              <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker B:</span>
                <select name="speakerB">
                  <option>Statement 1</option>
                  <option>Statement 2</option>
                  <option>Statement 3</option>
                  <option>Statement 4</option>
                  <option>Statement 5</option>
                  <option>Statement 6</option>
                  <option>Statement 7</option>
                </select>
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker C:</span>
                <select name="speakerC">
                  <option>Statement 1</option>
                  <option>Statement 2</option>
                  <option>Statement 3</option>
                  <option>Statement 4</option>
                  <option>Statement 5</option>
                  <option>Statement 6</option>
                  <option>Statement 7</option>
                </select>
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker D:</span>
                <select name="speakerD">
                  <option>Statement 1</option>
                  <option>Statement 2</option>
                  <option>Statement 3</option>
                  <option>Statement 4</option>
                  <option>Statement 5</option>
                  <option>Statement 6</option>
                  <option>Statement 7</option>
                </select>
              </label>
              <p></p>

              <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker E:</span>
                <select name="speakerE">
                  <option>Statement 1</option>
                  <option>Statement 2</option>
                  <option>Statement 3</option>
                  <option>Statement 4</option>
                  <option>Statement 5</option>
                  <option>Statement 6</option>
                  <option>Statement 7</option>
                </select>
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker F:</span>
                <select name="speakerF">
                  <option>Statement 1</option>
                  <option>Statement 2</option>
                  <option>Statement 3</option>
                  <option>Statement 4</option>
                  <option>Statement 5</option>
                  <option>Statement 6</option>
                  <option>Statement 7</option>
                </select>
              </label>
            </td>

            <!-- Listening - Part 2-->
            <td id="col2">
              <span class="spc7"><u>Statement A</u>:</span>
              <label>1) - True:
                <input name="statementA" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2) - False:
                <input name="statementA" type="radio" value="2) - False">
              </label>
              <label>3) - Not Stated:
                <input name="statementA" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Statement B</u>:</span>
              <label>1) - True:
                <input name="statementB" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2) - False:
                <input name="statementB" type="radio" value="2) - False">
              </label>
              <label>3) - Not Stated:
                <input name="statementB" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Statement C</u>:</span>
              <label>1) - True:
                <input name="statementC" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2) - False:
                <input name="statementC" type="radio" value="2) - False">
              </label>
              <label>3) - Not Stated:
                <input name="statementC" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Statement D</u>:</span>
              <label>1) - True:
                <input name="statementD" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2) - False:
                <input name="statementD" type="radio" value="2) - False">
              </label>
              <label>3) - Not Stated:
                <input name="statementD" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Statement E</u>:</span>
              <label>1) - True:
                <input name="statementE" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2) - False:
                <input name="statementE" type="radio" value="2) - False">
              </label>
              <label>3) - Not Stated:
                <input name="statementE" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Statement F</u>:</span>
              <label>1) - True:
                <input name="statementF" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2) - False:
                <input name="statementF" type="radio" value="2) - False">
              </label>
              <label>3) - Not Stated:
                <input name="statementF" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Statement G</u>:</span>
              <label>1) - True:
                <input name="statementG" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2) - False:
                <input name="statementG" type="radio" value="2) - False">
              </label>
              <label>3) - Not Stated:
                <input name="statementG" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
              </label>
            </td>

            <!-- Listening - Part 3-->
            <td id="col3">
              <span class="spc7"><u>Question 3</u>:</span>
              <label>1)
                <input name="question 3" type="radio" value="1" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2)
                <input name="question 3" type="radio" value="2">
              </label>
              <label>3)
                <input name="question 3" type="radio" value="3">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Question 4</u>:</span>
              <label>1)
                <input name="question 4" type="radio" value="1" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2)
                <input name="question 4" type="radio" value="2">
              </label>
              <label>3)
                <input name="question 4" type="radio" value="3">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Question 5</u>:</span>
              <label>1)
                <input name="question 5" type="radio" value="1" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2)
                <input name="question 5" type="radio" value="2">
              </label>
              <label>3)
                <input name="question 5" type="radio" value="3">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Question 6</u>:</span>
              <label>1)
                <input name="question 6" type="radio" value="1" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2)
                <input name="question 6" type="radio" value="2">
              </label>
              <label>3)
                <input name="question 6" type="radio" value="3">
              </label>


              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Question 7</u>:</span>
              <label>1)
                <input name="question 7" type="radio" value="1" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2)
                <input name="question 7" type="radio" value="2">
              </label>
              <label>3)
                <input name="question 7" type="radio" value="3">
              </label>


              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Question 8</u>:</span>
              <label>1)
                <input name="question 8" type="radio" value="1" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2)
                <input name="question 8" type="radio" value="2">
              </label>
              <label>3)
                <input name="question 8" type="radio" value="3">
              </label>

              <p></p>
              <span class="spc7"><u>Question 9</u>:</span>
              <label>1)
                <input name="question 9" type="radio" value="1" checked>
              </label>
              <label>2)
                <input name="question 9" type="radio" value="2">
              </label>
              <label>3)
                <input name="question 9" type="radio" value="3">
              </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Create Listening GIFT">
    </div>
```

or

set its style as display:flex and set the direction to column and then align-content as center

Check this code snippet

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
input[ type="button"] {
  flex: 0 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tablecenter">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="height:80px">
          <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 1</span>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px">
          <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 2</span>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px">
          <span class="tableheader">Listening - Part 3</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <!-- Listening - Part 1-->
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="col1">
          <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker A:</span>
            <select name="speakerA">
              <option>Statement 1</option>
              <option>Statement 2</option>
              <option>Statement 3</option>
              <option>Statement 4</option>
              <option>Statement 5</option>
              <option>Statement 6</option>
              <option>Statement 7</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <p></p>

          <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker B:</span>
            <select name="speakerB">
              <option>Statement 1</option>
              <option>Statement 2</option>
              <option>Statement 3</option>
              <option>Statement 4</option>
              <option>Statement 5</option>
              <option>Statement 6</option>
              <option>Statement 7</option>
            </select>
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker C:</span>
            <select name="speakerC">
              <option>Statement 1</option>
              <option>Statement 2</option>
              <option>Statement 3</option>
              <option>Statement 4</option>
              <option>Statement 5</option>
              <option>Statement 6</option>
              <option>Statement 7</option>
            </select>
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker D:</span>
            <select name="speakerD">
              <option>Statement 1</option>
              <option>Statement 2</option>
              <option>Statement 3</option>
              <option>Statement 4</option>
              <option>Statement 5</option>
              <option>Statement 6</option>
              <option>Statement 7</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <p></p>

          <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker E:</span>
            <select name="speakerE">
              <option>Statement 1</option>
              <option>Statement 2</option>
              <option>Statement 3</option>
              <option>Statement 4</option>
              <option>Statement 5</option>
              <option>Statement 6</option>
              <option>Statement 7</option>
            </select>
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <label> <span class="spc7">Speaker F:</span>
            <select name="speakerF">
              <option>Statement 1</option>
              <option>Statement 2</option>
              <option>Statement 3</option>
              <option>Statement 4</option>
              <option>Statement 5</option>
              <option>Statement 6</option>
              <option>Statement 7</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </td>

        <!-- Listening - Part 2-->
        <td id="col2">
          <span class="spc7"><u>Statement A</u>:</span>
          <label>1) - True:
            <input name="statementA" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2) - False:
            <input name="statementA" type="radio" value="2) - False">
          </label>
          <label>3) - Not Stated:
            <input name="statementA" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Statement B</u>:</span>
          <label>1) - True:
            <input name="statementB" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2) - False:
            <input name="statementB" type="radio" value="2) - False">
          </label>
          <label>3) - Not Stated:
            <input name="statementB" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Statement C</u>:</span>
          <label>1) - True:
            <input name="statementC" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2) - False:
            <input name="statementC" type="radio" value="2) - False">
          </label>
          <label>3) - Not Stated:
            <input name="statementC" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Statement D</u>:</span>
          <label>1) - True:
            <input name="statementD" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2) - False:
            <input name="statementD" type="radio" value="2) - False">
          </label>
          <label>3) - Not Stated:
            <input name="statementD" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Statement E</u>:</span>
          <label>1) - True:
            <input name="statementE" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2) - False:
            <input name="statementE" type="radio" value="2) - False">
          </label>
          <label>3) - Not Stated:
            <input name="statementE" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Statement F</u>:</span>
          <label>1) - True:
            <input name="statementF" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2) - False:
            <input name="statementF" type="radio" value="2) - False">
          </label>
          <label>3) - Not Stated:
            <input name="statementF" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Statement G</u>:</span>
          <label>1) - True:
            <input name="statementG" type="radio" value="1) - True" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2) - False:
            <input name="statementG" type="radio" value="2) - False">
          </label>
          <label>3) - Not Stated:
            <input name="statementG" type="radio" value="3) - Not Stated">
          </label>
        </td>

        <!-- Listening - Part 3-->
        <td id="col3">
          <span class="spc7"><u>Question 3</u>:</span>
          <label>1)
            <input name="question 3" type="radio" value="1" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2)
            <input name="question 3" type="radio" value="2">
          </label>
          <label>3)
            <input name="question 3" type="radio" value="3">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Question 4</u>:</span>
          <label>1)
            <input name="question 4" type="radio" value="1" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2)
            <input name="question 4" type="radio" value="2">
          </label>
          <label>3)
            <input name="question 4" type="radio" value="3">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Question 5</u>:</span>
          <label>1)
            <input name="question 5" type="radio" value="1" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2)
            <input name="question 5" type="radio" value="2">
          </label>
          <label>3)
            <input name="question 5" type="radio" value="3">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Question 6</u>:</span>
          <label>1)
            <input name="question 6" type="radio" value="1" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2)
            <input name="question 6" type="radio" value="2">
          </label>
          <label>3)
            <input name="question 6" type="radio" value="3">
          </label>


          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Question 7</u>:</span>
          <label>1)
            <input name="question 7" type="radio" value="1" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2)
            <input name="question 7" type="radio" value="2">
          </label>
          <label>3)
            <input name="question 7" type="radio" value="3">
          </label>


          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Question 8</u>:</span>
          <label>1)
            <input name="question 8" type="radio" value="1" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2)
            <input name="question 8" type="radio" value="2">
          </label>
          <label>3)
            <input name="question 8" type="radio" value="3">
          </label>

          <p></p>
          <span class="spc7"><u>Question 9</u>:</span>
          <label>1)
            <input name="question 9" type="radio" value="1" checked>
          </label>
          <label>2)
            <input name="question 9" type="radio" value="2">
          </label>
          <label>3)
            <input name="question 9" type="radio" value="3">
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Create Listening GIFT">
</div>
html css
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but that actually centers the button. And I want my button to be on the left so that its left margin == table left margin.

Comment: I guess so, because I use this:

        #col1           { width: 250px; }
        #col2           { width: 410px; }
        #col3           { width: 220px; }

So it should be 880 px

Comment: modified the code ..as we already know the width of table...you can set it on div and set its margin left and right as auto

Answer (score 1):

Try to add width as a percentage (98%) to the class .tablecenter as bellow

```
.tablecenter    { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;width:98% }
```

and warp the button using a div with a same class or add a new class with same attributes as above

```
<div class="tablecenter">
    <input type = "button" value = "Create Listening GIFT">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, could you clarify it please? Why do we apply the same class to the table and the button but the table gets centered while the button doesn't?

Comment: Because we have only make the element center to the parent element, In you example TABLE is our element and the parent element is DIV,

Comment: please see our attributes in the given class only the margin-left and margin-right using these attributes child elements are not getting centered

Answer (score 1):

I took a slightly different approach.
my css

```
    .tablecenter {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

        border-bottom:none;
    }
   tbody td, thead th {
        border:solid black thin
    }
```

and the bottom of the table...

```
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="button" value="Create Listening GIFT"></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```